# Proof check on the fact that the bounday is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

As a definition of boundary I want to use:

Take $X$ a topological space, then the boundary of $A$ is

$$Bnd(A) = \{ x \in X | \forall{\delta>0} B(x,\delta) \cap A \ne \emptyset, B(x,\delta) \cap A^c \ne \emptyset \} $$

I proceed this way: $Bnd(A)$ is closed $\iff Bnd(A)^c$ is open (definition of closed set).

$x \in Bnd(A)^c$ means that $x \in \{ x \in  X | \exists \delta>0 B(x,\delta)\cap A = \emptyset$ or $B(x,\delta)\cap A^c = \emptyset \}$ but from this set we can always find an open ball centred at x included in the set taking $B(x, \delta)$ (all elements of the open ball belong to $Bnd(A)^c$.
Because $x$ was arbitrary it follows that $Bnd(A)^c$ is open and so $Bnd(A)$ is closed.

Is this correct? if it is, would you have added some notation or sophistication to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will work! As a pointer, I would stay away from writing proofs in set-builder notation (assuming they are proofs you will want other people to read.) If it helps you write the proof in the first place then by all means use it to your advantage. But it can be a bit cumbersome for an outside reader to unpack the set-builder notation, and that will slow down the flow of reading the proof. As an example, instead of saying

> "$x \in \text{Bd}(A)^c$ means that $x \in \{ x \in  X | \exists \delta>0 B(x,\delta)\cap A = \emptyset$ or $B(x,\delta)\cap A^c = \emptyset \}$"

say

> "$x \in \text{Bd}(A)^c$ means that we can find an open set $U$ containing $x$ where either $U\cap A = \emptyset$ or $U\cap A^c = \emptyset$."

The fact that $U$ is open can be stated without mentioning a $\delta$. As long as $X$ is a metric space a reader should know that they always *could* stick an open ball of some $\delta$ inside the open $U$ I mentioned.

Comment: I think you should re-write your last two sentences of the proof into moe grammatical form. It seems a bit  incoherent but I think you have the right idea...BTW what you dealing with is a metric space , which is a type of topological space.Not all topological spaces are capable of having metrics.